# Image not loading on specific viewport widths

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have a problem with broken links when using next-image.

What's happening is that sometimes my images load on a certain viewport width (say 1200px), but if I shrink it down to mobile size, the image links will be broken.

Upon checking the console, there will be an error logged with a 500 status.
`http://[frontend_url]/_next/image?url=http://[backend_api]/uploads/hero_Image_b538a45842.png&w=750&q=75`

I can solve this by setting `unoptimized = true` but that would negate the benefits of the Image component...

The most confusing thing is this: why is Image loading the image on larger widths, but not on smaller widths?

EDIT: Node error found

````
0|next-sta |   path: '/usr/local/lsws/NextApp/html/node/.next/cache/images/j8X3FWLiJlicemGC-Qioge3VvTjbRkDYuIKNy2zXAjM=/1627911151769.RMzOowFH4OzxMfIA8G2Qeu9NBvQpi3uHrw9gUg5r5mQ=.webp'
0|next-sta | }
0|next-sta | [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/lsws/NextApp/html/node/.next/cache/images/cV6oT2gdWQ2+Xgc7AgKESqo2NncqsInXIA0WbcuTY4M=/1627911151770.86QROHkZcFs61Wxlt0dGI1kFyEvTpcD2qFXF7U6ueZg=.webp']```
````

Comment: What is the nextjs console logged in the node output?
Are you also placing the image in the `public` directory where next has access?

Comment: How are you using `next/image` and what does your `next.config.js` look like?

Comment: Hello the node output shows an error, added in EDIT on the original post. The images are retrieved through Strapi CMS's API.

@juliomalves, I am using next/image in responsive mode with width and height set to 1000 (it's a square image). My next.config.js has these lines:

```images: {
    domains: ["[backend]"],
  }```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue when running the app locally with `next build && next start`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It looks like it's related to folder permissions in Linux. Once I gave full permissions to the user who ran the npm process, everything *seems* to be fine.